# How to show UIActivityIndicatorView while rest api getting data from server

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I want to show UIActivityIndicatorView while data is being received from the server. I have tried that but it's not visible:

```
public partial class MyFirst: UIViewController
    {
        UIActivityIndicatorView spinner;

        public MyFirst(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();

              picker.ValueChanged += (sender, e) =>
             {
                 loadDetails(picker.SelectedValueId);
             };

            spinner = new UIActivityIndicatorView
            {
                Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, 60, 60),
                Color = UIColor.Black
            };

            spinner.Center = new CGPoint(View.Bounds.Width / 2, 
            View.Bounds.Height / 2);
            View.AddSubview(spinner);

       }

      public void loadDetails(string userId)
      {
          spinner.StartAnimating();

          var client = new RestClient("my web service URL");
          var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
          request.AddParameter("userid", userId);

          IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
          var content = response.Content;

          var deserializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FleetList>(content);
          var fleets = deserializedObject.ownersdara;

          if (fleets.Count > 0)
          {
               spinner.StopAnimating();
               tableView.Source = new tableSource(fleets .ToArray());
               tableView.ReloadData();
          }               
     }
}
```

Here I have used restsharp for calling a web service. Now when I change the value from picker then it will call the `loadDetails` function. In this function, I have written `spinner.StartAnimating();` but its not showing.

I am binding the TableView data source after getting all data from the server.

How can I `show UIActivityIndicatorView` when the rest API is called while receiving data and after getting all data hide it again?

Comment: you may need to call StartAnimating on the UI thread

Comment: i have also tried -> `InvokeOnMainThread ( () => {
     spinner.StartAnimating();
});` but still its not working.

Answer (score 0):

I have called api on **viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)** because i wanted to fetch data when the screen appears. I am fetching data from firebase here.
Always use a completion handler while fetching data from database, which will fetch data in the background while displaying a spinner and as soon as the data is fetched, it will shown to the user.

```
   //Start your spinner before calling api
    self.startAnimating()
    var ref: DatabaseReference!
    ref = Database.database().reference(fromURL: kFirebaseLink)
    ref.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        print("data fetched of : \(snapshot)")
        if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
            //fill array from the data fetched from database

            //Stop your spinner here when your data is fetched.
            self.stopAnimating()
            if self.array.count > 0 {
                 // Data fetced from database. populate table
                 self.tblView.reloadData()
            }else{
                 // there are no data in Database.

            }
        }

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I made test on my side ,you should set `ActivityIndicatorViewStyle` to the `UIActivityIndicatorView` ,after that it should be able to work.

Comment: Can you explain it more.?

Comment: @deepak I want to know the result first,did it work or not?

Comment: Got your answer but i have solved using `async ` methods to show.